# How to hide dns when someone whois me by use domainsbyproxy?

Tags: privacy-policy

i register domain with godaddy and i use addon privacy protect by domainsbyproxy but still show dns server when whois? how to make its to private?

Comment: How do you expect people to resolve your domain name if your name servers are kept secret?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using the domain (email, website, etc.) then you could just remove the DNS records for the domain.

The WhoisPrivacy only hides the information on who owns and administers the domain.  That is all a whois record shows.  A private domain, in your case godaddy domains by proxy, is where the information is defaulted to godaddy.  Only law enforcement is able to get the actual information of who owns the domain.

I strongly suggest not getting domain privacy. If you dont want to put your business address or home address then register a mail box for the addresses on your domain.  I seldom check a whois, but when i see a private whois, it just turns me off.

It also makes no sense if you have a public website that shows an address or phone number to have a privately registered domain.

As for DNS. Godaddy gives you the ability to use their DNS servers, (create dns records right there), or you can use a DNS service such as Zerigo.com.  DNS servers also have WHOIS records, as do IP Addresses, but these are for the actual servers that manage the name to record transaltions and not your domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Domains By Proxy is only able to hide your personal information to help protect you from spam. You can not hide your DNS information, by doing so will give all of your users an error when they try to view your site.